# Trying to exit the program, get endless loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops, infinite-loop, exit

I am a beginner, trying to exit one of my first programs in Python, but just get endless loop.
Can't understand what's going wrong.

```
question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
some_list = []

while True:
    if question not in some_list:
        some_list.append(question)
        question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
    else:
        print("\n\nPress enter to exit")
        print(some_list)
```

Comment: use `break` to exit the while loop

Comment: You have used the predefined name `list` for a variable which will crash you program.Use a `break ` after getting question input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!
If you want to break the loop like you wrote in one of your prints: "\n\nPress enter to exit", you can use the following solution:

```
while True:
  x = input()
  if len(x) == 0:
    break
```

The full code will be:

```
question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
list = []

while True:
    question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
    if len(question) == 0:
        break
    if question not in list:
        list.append(question)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Never use built is function as variables. You basically are assinign the number 4 to number 5: 4=5. Which is wrong. There I fixed it.

```
question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")

something = []


while True:
    if question not in something:
        something.append(question)
        question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
    else:
        print("\n\nPress enter to exit") 
        print(something)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```
question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ") 
alist = []

while True:
    if question not in alist:
        alist.append(question)
        question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list/type 'quit' to exit: ")
        if question=='quit': 
            break
print(alist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
list = []

while True:
    if question not in list:
         list.append(question)
         question = input("Please enter your 'to do' list: ")
    else:
        input("\n\nPress enter to exit")
        print(list)
        break
```